# Pythonic way to iterate through loops

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to implement the following code in more of a pythonic way:

```
odd_rows = table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'odd'}) #contain all tr tags
even_rows = table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'even'})

for rows in odd_rows:              #rows equal 1 <tr> tag 
    rows.findAll('td')             #find all the <td> tags located in that one <tr> tag
    for row in rows.findAll('td'): #find one <td> tag
        print row                  #print that <td> tag

for rows in even_rows:
    rows.findAll('td')
    for row in rows.findAll('td'):
        print row
```

the line `row.findAll('td')` shows my logic

Comment: The line `rows.findAll('td')` by itself doesn't do anything

Comment: When you do `rows.findAll('td')` the operation is performed. When you do `for row in rows.findAll('td'):` the operation is performed AGAIN. The first is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
for row in table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'odd'}) + table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'class':'even'}):
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        print cell
```

From a performance standpoint, your original code is better. Combining two lists does use resources.

However, unless you are writing code for Google scale, I agree with this quote.

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.
>    -  Hal Abelson, Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs

There is more than one way to do it. Write code the way that you feel is most readable to you. The computer can figure out the details.

Comment: Could you explain what the "+" does? so if for example I had 3 class types, I would need to add 3 `table.findAll()`?

Comment: @JamesHallen `table.findAll` returns a list, so `table.findAll(...) + table.findAll(...)` is combining the two lists, no different than doing `[1, 2] + [3, 4]`

Answer (score 3):

```
for cls in ("odd", "even"):
    for rows in table.findAll('tr', class_=cls):
        for row in rows.findAll('td'):
            print row
```

Comment: If you don't care about the order, pass a tuple of classes to `class_` and it'll match elements having either of them.

Comment: Should you second line be `table.find_all` or `table.findAll`?

Comment: @JamesHallen: If you're using BeautifulSoup3, `findAll` is the only one that works. `find_all` is the preferred syntax for BS4.